# Determinant of enlarged matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A$ be the $n\times n$ matrix with entries $A_{ij}$ and consider the enlarged $2n\times 2n$ matrix
$$\tilde A=\begin{pmatrix}A_{11} & 0 & A_{12} & 0 & \dots & A_{1n} & 0 \\ 0 & A_{11} & 0 & A_{12} & \dots & 0 & A_{1n} \\ A_{21} & 0 & A_{22} & 0 & \dots & A_{2n} & 0 \\ 0 & A_{21} & 0 & A_{22} & \dots & 0 & A_{2n} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ A_{n1}  
 & 0 & A_{n2} & 0 & \dots & A_{nn} & 0 \\ 0  
 & A_{n1} & 0 & A_{n2} & \dots & 0 & A_{nn}\end{pmatrix} $$
that is, the matrix where every row is duplicated and padded with zeros. Is there a simple formula for the determinant of $\tilde A$ given the determinant of $A$?

Comment: your rows are not independent, determinant is zero

Comment: @zwim sorry. wrong matrix!

Comment: By moving the odd-indexed rows and columns to the front, the matrix becomes $\pmatrix{A\\ &A}$. Hence its determinant is equal to $(\det A)^2$.

Comment: @user1551 isn't your result in disagreement with the answer below?

Comment: @user1551 I think you mean that the matrix becomes $\tilde A=\text{diag}(\underbrace{A,...,A}_{n\text{ times}})$.

Comment: No, not $n$ times, but only twice. $A$ is $n\times n$. $\tilde{A}$ is $2n\times2n$. $\operatorname{diag}(\underbrace{A,\ldots,A}_{n \text{ times}})$ is $n^2\times n^2$.

Comment: @user1551 You are correct of course, my bad. Then, is the answer below incorrect? As far as I can see if we can write $\tilde A=A\otimes I$, where $I$ the $2\times 2$ identity matrix, then $\det\tilde A=(\det A)^n\det I = (\det A)^n\ne  (\det A)^2$ for $n\ne 2$. Am I missing something simple?

Comment: In general, $\det(A_{n\times n}\otimes B_{m\times m})=\det(A)^m\det(B)^n$. In particular, $\det(A_{n\times n}\otimes I_2)=\det(A)^2\det(I_2)^n=\det(A)^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$\widetilde{A} = A \otimes I,$$
for $\otimes$ the Kronecker product, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product. The determinant of Kronecker products admits a closed form, which is also presented in the same wikipedia article.

Answer (score 2):

Consider small case for $n=2$. You can generalize the process for any $n$.

Say we have $A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$.

Then $\bar{A}=\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 & b & 0 \\ 0 & a & 0 & b \\ c & 0 & d & 0 \\ 0 & c & 0 & d \end{pmatrix}$.

Now interchange $C_{2}$ with $C_{3}$ to get $\begin{pmatrix} a & b & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & a & b \\ c & d & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & c & d \end{pmatrix}$.

Now interchange $R_{2}$ with $R_{3}$ to get $\begin{pmatrix} a & b & 0 & 0 \\ c & d & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & a & b \\ 0 & 0 & c & d \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & A\end{pmatrix}$.

For any $n\times n$ matrix $A$, we can perform such row and column operations to get $\bar{A}=\begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & A\end{pmatrix}$.

Also note that total row and column operations required to simply $\bar{A}$ are even in numbers for any $n$. So, we have $\det(\bar{A})=(\det(A))^2$